# I want to find if there is number in my string or it's just letters? c programing

Tags: c

so I work in c, and I wrote a function that should do the trick but it doesn't work and I didn't know why.
this is the function:

```
int ChekingStirg(char *arr, int size_arr)
{
    int i, p = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < size_arr; i++)
    {
        char a = arr[i];
        if ((a > 'z' || a < 'A' || a > 'Z' && a< 'a'))
        {
            p = 1;//If p=1, there is only string
        }
        else
        {
            p = 0;
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Any reason for not using [`isdigit()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha)?

Comment: That `if` statement doesn't look right to me, you should be explicit with the `&&` condition when using with `||`. Something like `if ((a > 'z' || a < 'A' || a > 'Z') && a< 'a')`

Comment: Post is unclear what should be returned with `"@#$"`, `""`, `"0x123"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to return in your condition, or you may change value of `p` in next loop iteration. This can easily happen in first character is digit and all other are alphabetical. So your code can be like this:

```
int ChekingString(char *arr, int size_arr)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < size_arr; i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(arr[i]))
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int CheckingString(const char *arr, int size_arr) {
    int i, p = 0;
    // p means "contains number"
    for (i = 0; i < size_arr; i++)
    {
        char a = arr[i];
        // if ((a > 'z' || a < 'A' || a > 'Z' && a< 'a'))
        if (isdigit(a))
        {
            p = 1
            // If p == 1, there is number
        }
        else
        {
            // Do nothing here. Don't reset p to 0
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

There's one thing to note: Subsequent appearance of letters do **not** overwrite the existence of **previous** digits. So you shouldn't change `p` if you find a non-digit.

Also, use `isdigit()` for an easier job as well as better readability. Don't forget to include `ctype.h` header.

Other irrelevant changes I have done in the above code:

- Renamed `ChekingStirg` to `CheckingString` (I believe it's a baad speelliing of English)
- Changed `arr` to `const char*` as you don't modify `arr` in your function.

Comment: `isdigit(int)` is UB when `a < 0`.  One way to avoid that problem: `if (isdigit((unsigned char) a))`

Comment: sorry I didn't write it but I can"t use Isdigit, that is why i tried to build this function